# How to get jwt token for authentication in azure apim endpoint through Microsoft Actionable Message Card

Tags: http, jwt, azure-api-management, adaptive-cards

We are developing an Actionable Message Card that calls an Azure APIM endpoint, but we are having problems authenticating, the response is always 401-Unauthorized.
This is the configuration of the Accept action:

```
"type": "Action.Http",
"id": "Accept",
"title": "Approve",
"method": "POST",
"url": "{foo_url}",
"body": "{bar_body}",
"headers": [
    {
        "name": "Authorization",
        "value": "{bearer token}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Content-type",
        "value": "application/json"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
        "value": "{foo_ocp-sub-key}"
    }
],
"isPrimary": true,
"style": "positive"
```

On the Azure APIM side:
The API security setting "User Authorization" is set to "No", however the jwt token is validated in the inbound policies. We are not sure this is the best approach, but it is what it is. We are open to suggestions about this as well.

Using the same headers as in the action configuration in Postman, we have successfully called the API endpoint, but when pressing the "Approve" button in the Actionable Message Card the response is always 401-Unauthorized. Even when using the same bearer token that works in the Postman request.

Do you have any ideas about what could be causing this? And how to overcome it?